# Merging git branch to another source

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-merge

i have created a feature branch from branch_1, then branch_1.1 was created from branch_1. Now i want to merge changes from my feature branch to branch_1.1, what is the proper way of doing this? (i don't mind squashing all commits from feature branch into one commit) 
[image: branch relation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the commit history for now as below:

```
    master   branch_1
      |         |
...---A---...---B---...---C   branch_1.1
                 \            
                  D---...---E  feature
```

You can **merge `feature` branch into `branch_1.1` directly** by:

```
git checkout branch_1.1
git merge feature
```

The commit history will be:

```
    master   branch_1
      |         |
...---A---...---B---...---C---M  branch_1.1
                 \           /
                  D---...---E  feature
```

Or you can **merge with squash and rebase**:

```
git checkout feature
git pull origin branch_1.1 --rebase --squash
git checkout branch_1.1
git merge feature
```

The commit history will be:

```
    master   branch_1
      |         |
...---A---...---B---...---C---S  branch_1.1, feature
```

Comment: which of these approaches in better to maintain proper version control?

Comment: If you want to make the commit history easy to read it's a merge operation, then you'd better choose option 1. And if you want to keep the commit history clean and liner, then you'd better use option 2.